# CUDA - Precision difference in Release version between with and without debug information

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA application, which I compile once for a Release version twice: once **with debug info** (-G used) and once **without debug info**. I run the application which does some computations on floats (including functions such as expf, sinf, cosf, etc.).
I notice that there are slight differences in the numbers created by the two versions, here they are side by side:

```
0: (-8.000000,0.000000,0.000000)        0: (-8.000000,0.000000,0.000000)
1: (-8.212574,-0.112065,0.970697)       1: (-8.212575,-0.112065,0.970697)
2: (-8.365530,-0.250361,1.949206)       2: (-8.365531,-0.250361,1.949206)
3: (-8.332600,-0.251884,2.948662)       3: (-8.332601,-0.251885,2.948662)
4: (-8.593035,-0.619825,3.841295)       4: (-8.593036,-0.619826,3.841295)
5: (-8.507285,-0.778658,4.824870)       5: (-8.507286,-0.778658,4.824870)
6: (-8.441058,-1.001207,5.797539)       6: (-8.441058,-1.001207,5.797539)
7: (-8.680929,-1.051136,6.767059)       7: (-8.680929,-1.051136,6.767059)
```

These are the first 7 values (both versions start with -8,0,0). As you can see at this point there are only small differences in the 6th digit after the decimal point. However, I use these during rotation matrix computation, so after 1000 of these, the differences add up to be quite significant.

I'm not adding the source code because it is very big and quite complicated.

I was wondering why is there a difference in the first place. I know that there are vast differences between debug and release versions in terms of optimizations. I guess there are similar differences between release with and without debug info. However, how could optimizations change calculation precision?

Comment: Compiler optimizations can slightly change the outcomes as compared to non-optimized codes since they can change the execution order of the instructions to priviledge performance and so they can change, for example, the roundings of the intermediate results.

Comment: One optimization that frequently affects numerical results (usually in a positive way, meaning improved accuracy) is the contraction of floating-point multiplies and adds into a fused multiply-add operation. You can turn this off with the nvcc command line switch `-fmad=false` (note that this usually has a negative impact on performance).

Comment: @njuffa: So far that's the difference I also noticed, so this actually means that the Release version should be more accurate, although this is the version that's giving me grief. I'm still investigating.
P.S. thank you for the suggestion for `-fmad=false`. I'm now positive that this is definitely the only difference.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is giving me grief"? You can determine which computation is more accurate by comparing both to a higher precision reference computation. In individual cases where multiple error sources combine it is certainly possible that not using FMA (fused-multiple add) results in a more accurate final result due to the fortuitous cancellation of error terms. By a reduction in rounding error (one rounding instead of two) and reduction of cancelation errors (during effective subtractions), use of FMA provides more accurate results _on average_.

Comment: I would suggest reading the following whitepaper, as well as the references it cites, if you haven't done so yet: https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/NVIDIA-CUDA-Floating-Point.pdf

Comment: @njuffa:
"Giving me grief" meant that the FMA enabled computation led to a state which I didn't think was possible in my program. Upon further inspection it turned out that the state was indeed theoretically possible, and thus I found a genuine bug in my program. Thank you for the suggestion of comparing to a higher precision reference computation, I'll do that. Also thank you for the whitepaper link, I actually read it after your first comment on FMA. Too bad you didn't post as an answer, I would have marked it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point arithmetic isn't associative, so the order of operations matters. If you change compiler options (like with/without debugging), the code emitted by the compiler can, and usually is, rather different. Something as simple as the reordering of a few floating point instructions can be enough to change the result.

The only way to be sure is to look at the final code running on the device. NVIDIA supply a tool `cuobjdump` which you can use to disassemble CUDA object code. If your perform a side-by-side comparison of the kernel compiled each of the two ways, it might be possible to find where differences in two floating point results arise for a given input.